# IE Java script error Unable to get value of the property '0':

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have an:

```
<img id="uploadedimage" alt="uploaded image" src="" width="250px" height="250px"/>
```

and have a div to display the image once the user has selected their image using this JQuery code:

```
$('#BusinessImage').change(function (ev) {

            var f = ev.target.files[0];
            var fr = new FileReader();
            var IsImage = false;

            // check the file is an image
            if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
                IsImage = true;
            }

            fr.onload = function (ev2) {
                if (IsImage) {
                    $('#uploadedimage').attr('src', ev2.target.result);  
                }
            };

            if (IsImage) {
                fr.readAsDataURL(f);
                ValidFileUpload();
            }
            else {
                InvalidFileUpload();
            }
        });
```

Of course this code works great in every other browser apart from Satans browser, Internet Explorer. I get this error:

```
Line: 108
Character: 13
Code: 0
Error Message: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this as it works great in FFX and Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code on line 108? Also, what version of IE?

Comment: Sorry, here it is     var f = ev.target.files[0];
I am also using IE 9 and tried it in 8, both don't work

Comment: Need a jsfiddle of this one. IE is telling you that ev.target doesn't contain a files array.

Comment: The File API and the FileReader API only works in IE 10+.  http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader

Comment: thats good news! Damn IE, is there any other alternative? :)

Comment: There is a "labs" feature to [install the FileAPI into IE9](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5labs/prototypes/fileapi/fileapi/info/).  I've never tried it.  Other than that, IE can't do this, and there's no other way (short of sending the file to the server-side, and having it return the URL of the file).  Try using a real web browser :-P

Answer (score 8):

".files" work only on those browsers that support HTML5.

Files is supported on IE10 but for IE9 and early versions you must use other way to get path.:

To check if files is supported:

```
if( ev.target.files ){
  //supported
  console.log( ev.target.files[0] );
}else{
  //.files not supported
  console.log( ev.target.value );
}
```

Comment: Yep, says not suported :( Is there any other alternative?

Comment: My answer show you what to do when files is not supported. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes! It worked but it gave another error: : 'FileReader' is undefined

Comment: It is other issue than your original question. FileReader is only supported by HTML5 complaints. For support old browsers, use a third party tool that has been fixed all of the common issues, just a tool like this: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/